# Paginação de table com AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, java-ee, rest, vraptor

Estava tentando colocar uma paginação em minha tabela, depois de uma ajuda consegui resolver parcialmente o problema, porém não ficou da forma que eu esperava.

Já consigo pegar a `currentPage` a cada clique no <`pagination>` o problema está em como carregar os dados quando mudo de página. Da forma antiga estava utilizando `setFirstResult` e `setMaxResults` do `Hibernate` porém quando eu clicava na próxima página ele sempre repetia a ultima linha da pagina anterior na nova página.

Qual seria a melhor maneira de pegar os dados de acordo com a página clicada, o que eu passo como parâmetro pra essa consulta?

**Front-end**

Controller:

```
angular.module("oraculo").controller("colaboradorController", function($scope, $routeParams, $location, colaboradorAPI, colaboradores){

        $scope.tamanhoMaximo = 6;
        $scope.currentPage = 1;
        $scope.totalItems = 60;
        //Onde fica armazenada toda a consulta
        $scope.colaboradores = colaboradores.data;
        ...
```

Pagina:

```
...
</table>
<pagination total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" max-size="tamanhoMaximo" class="pagination-sm" boundary-links="true" rotate="false" num-pages="numPages" ng-click="loading(currentPage)"></pagination>
```

---

**Back-end**

DAO:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Colaborador> listarColaboradores() {
        List<Colaborador> lista = new ArrayList<>();
        Session sessao = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction transacao = null;
        try {
            transacao = sessao.beginTransaction();
            Query consulta = sessao.getNamedQuery("Colaborador.listar");
            lista = consulta.list();
            transacao.commit();
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            sessao.close();
        }
        return lista;
    }
```

---

Estava fazendo dessa forma anteriormente:

DAO:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Colaborador> listarColaboradores(Integer paginaInicio, Integer count) {
        List<Colaborador> lista = new ArrayList<>();
        Session sessao = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction transacao = null;

        try {
            transacao = sessao.beginTransaction();
            Query consulta = sessao.getNamedQuery("Colaborador.listar");
            consulta.setFirstResult(paginaInicio);
            consulta.setMaxResults(count);
            lista = consulta.list();
            transacao.commit();
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            sessao.close();
        }
        return lista;
    }
```

Controller:

```
@Get
@Path("/colaboradores/{paginaInicio}")
    public void listarTodos(Integer paginaInicio) {
        result.use(Results.json())
       .withoutRoot()
       .from(colaboradorDAO.listarColaboradores(paginaInicio, 4))
       .serialize();
}
```

No **Front-end**:

Controller:

```
 $scope.loading = function(currentPage){
        console.log("currentPage: "+currentPage);
        colaboradorAPI.getColaboradores(currentPage).success(function(data){
            $scope.colaboradores = data;
        });
    }
```

Service:

```
var _getColaboradores = function(paginaInicio){
        return $http.get(config.baseURL + "/Oraculo/colaborador/colaboradores/" + paginaInicio);
};
```

Dessa forma chamo a função `loading` no `ng-click` do `pagination`, e passo o `currentPage`. Então passo o `currentPage` como parâmetro para o `back-end`.

Meu Projeto: https://github.com/sinkz/Angular

Comment: Pode postar como vc está enviando os valores do setFirstResult e setMaxResults nas três primeiras paginas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Aqui](https://github.com/emirdeliz/meus-projetos/blob/master/scroll-infinito-angular-rest-datafactory/src/main/webapp/assets/js) tenho um exemplo praticamente igual ao teu exceto que no meu caso é um scroll infinito semelhante ao do facebook.

Observer o seguinte, quando o usuário abrir a página serão apresentados **50**($scope.page.ini -> $scope.page.end) registros e a cada consulta **30** (**$scope.page.ini = 50, $scope.page.end = 80, $scope.page.ini = 80, $scope.page.end = 110 e assim por diante**) novos registros são apresentados.

```
AppPeople.controller("PeopleController", function($scope, $people) {
    $scope.data = [];
    $scope.page = {ini : 0, end : 50, increment: 30};
    $scope.busy = false;

    $scope.search = function() {
        $scope.busy = true;
        $scope.promise = $people.query({ini:$scope.page.ini, end: $scope.page.end}, function(response) { 
            $scope.loadPeople(response);
            $scope.incrementPageNumber();
            $scope.busy = false;
        }).$promise;
    };

    $scope.incrementPageNumber = function(){
        $scope.page.ini  = $scope.page.end;
        $scope.page.end += $scope.page.increment;
    };

    $scope.loadPeople = function(people){
        angular.forEach(people, function(item, i) {
            $scope.data.push(item);
        });
    };
});
```

Na sequência de click na próxima página você terá:

1. setFirstResult=0, setMaxResults=50
2. setFirstResult=50, setMaxResults=80
3. setFirstResult=80, setMaxResults=110
4. setFirstResult=110, setMaxResults=130
5. setFirstResult=130, setMaxResults=140

Observe: setFirstResult sempre recebe o setMaxResults anterior, exceto na primeira consulta aonde será 0. Já o setMaxResults sempre é incrementado de 30 em 30, exceto a primeira vez que irá exibir 50.

**Versão final: consulta.setFirstResult((pagina -1) * 6); consulta.setMaxResults(pagina * 6);**

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29529/discussion-between-techies-and-emir-marques).